# Concrete power problem

Tags: infamous-second-son

Ok so I know that when you defeat a D.U.P soldier you can drain them, but I completely chased them out of Seattle and I zeroed the D.U.P occupation, so I wanna know if there is a way for me to get concrete back.

Comment: is this for xcom or Infamous second son?

Comment: Infamous second son but it would not let me use that tag

Comment: What happened when you tried to use it that forced you to use a random, irrelevant tag? Sounds like a pretty serious bug.

Comment: Well it said I needed 300 reputation

Comment: @DevonLadd you was trying to [create a tag](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags) so you was doing something wrong as the Second Son tag already exists

Answer (score 1):

Even when DUP presence in a district has been reduced to 0%, you'll still run into DUP patrols and vehicles from time to time. There's no need to worry about accidentally eliminating your sources of concrete.